# Using istream& as a function parameter

Tags: c++, istream

I was told to use istream& as a parameter for an input function for my class Complex. Which is used in complex numbers. However I'm having trouble finding a good explanation of how to use istream.

I want to be able to cin to the real and imag variables.

```
class Complex
{
    public:
        void input(std::istream& in);
        void output(std::ostream& out);
        double getReal();
        double getImag();
        void setReal(double r);
        void setImag(double i);
    private:
        double real;
        double imag;
};

void Complex::input(istream& in)
{
    in >> real;
    in >> imag;
}
```

Comment: What is your assignment? It also completely depends what the `istream` is. (eg file input stream, etc.)

Comment: You say you want to be able to use `cin` with your class.  After you create an instance of `Complex`, you would then call `my_complex.input(std::cin);`.

Answer (score 0):

The signatures for

```
    void input(std::istream& in);
    void output(std::ostream& out);
```

should allow to chain the resulting stream state:

```
    std::istream& input(std::istream& in);
    std::ostream& output(std::ostream& out) const;
```

Thus these can be used in global overloads for your class:

```
 std::istream operator>>(std::istream& is, Complex& c ) {
     return c.input(is);
 }

 std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Complex& c ) {
     return c.output(os);
 }
```